# Casting problem in C++/CLI - won't compile

Tags: inheritance, casting, c++-cli

I have the following in C++/CLI: (take note of my errors in comments)

```
class Base{...}   

class Derived : public Base{...}

public ref class CliClass
{
    public:
    std::list<Base*> *myList;

    CliClass()
    {
    myList = new list<Base*>();
    }

    AddToList(Derived *derived)
    {
        myList->push_back(derived);
    }

    DoCast()
    {
        Derived *d = nullptr;

        int n = (int)myList->size();
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

        //this following does not compile
        //error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'Derived *'

        d = (Derived*)myList[i];    

        //I've also tried this -which does not compile
        //error C2682: cannot use 'dynamic_cast' to convert from 'std::list<_Ty>' to 'Derived *'

        d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(myList[i]);


        }
    }
}
```

I would like to cast myList[i] to the Derived type.. but it won't allow me.

Any suggestions on how to cast this properly? (compile and is run-time safe - i.e. won't blow up if wrong type)

Comment: Is this code even correct? It looks fishy to me. I don't know CLI, but how about this: 1) is `std:List` actually a real type? 2) you declare `myList` as an object, but then try to assign a pointer to it in `CliClass::CliClass()` -- how? 3) lists don't have random access, why are you writing `[i]`?

Comment: @Kerrek SB: 1) Yes. 2) Sorry myList should be a pointer. added that. 3) could that be my problem? it compiles.. I thought I could access by index

Comment: I never heard of a type `std::List` (capital `L`), is that a CLI extension? Anyway, what is the qualified type of `list` in `myList = new list<Base*>();`? Finally, with your changes now, `myList[i]` treats `myList` as an **array of lists**, surely not what you wanted!

Comment: @Kerrek SB: Sorry typo with the capital L (I can't put my real code online). How do I iterate through the list then? (doesn't that defeat the purpose of a list if you can't?)

Comment: `std:list` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `std::list`? Programming, unlike spoken language, leaves no room for vagaries, half-heartedness or inattention to detail. You got to get the spelling of stuff right, or you will have a *very* hard time getting people to work with you.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: omg. like I had std::List before, I told you that was a typo, then I put std:list.. which yes, a typo again. but you can't put the two together and figure out what I mean? You obviously do, but you are just trying to be plain old mean to me. I'm just trying to learn, and yes that means learning to have no typos, but you could try being less condescending when you correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got it all wrong. Assuming that you have several typos in your code and mean `std::list`, you are currently saying:

```
std::list<Base*> * myList;

/* ... */

myList[i] = /* ... */ ;
```

The last line treats `myList` as an **array of lists**, which you never created! The way to access list elements is by iteration.

Here is a skeleton rewrite, hopefully you'll be able to extract the fixes from that:

```
public ref class CliClass
{
public:
  std::list<Base*> * myList;

  CliClass() : myList(new std::list<Base*>()) { }

  DoCast()
  {
    for(auto it = myList->cbegin(), end = myList->cend(); it != end; ++it)
    {
      Derived * const d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(*it);
      /* do something useful with d */
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: That's much better, although a cast will still be needed for `d = *it;`.  Might I also suggest using a smart pointer instead of a raw pointer, it really helps prevent memory leaks.  I have an example posted at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1695/scoped-ptr-for-c-cli-ensure-managed-object-properly-frees-owned-native-object

Comment: Oh, d'oh, it's base-to-derived, not derived-to-base -- editing!

Comment: Re smart pointers: I'd have a whole page full of comments regarding that, but because it's CLI and I don't have or know CLI, I'm being careful. I don't know to what extent you can mix CLI and native constructions. Can you make `myList` a direct member object, for example?

Comment: No, you can't have a native object as a direct member of a managed type (imagine the mayhem if native objects started getting moved around by the garbage collector!), so a pointer is necessary.  But there's a fair amount of support code needed to manage its lifetime correctly, so it's worth writing a managed-type smart pointer once and reusing it.  Feel free to leave comments or questions on my example over at codereview (linked above).

Comment: @Ben: That's cool, thanks, I'll take a look! Unfortunately I don't have enough free resources to install a C++/CLI environment, so I'm a bit short on practical experience, but it sounds like a very promising and important technology that one should be aware of!

Answer (score 0):

C++ in std::list doesn't have an operator[].
Besides it's **std::list** and NOT **std:List**.

So the code is probably trying to convert the list into a **Derived*** and then will probably try to use the [] operator on the result.

So just find another way to store the data (for example `std::map<int,Base*>`).

Something like this:

```
std::for_each(myList.begin(), myList.end(), DoSomething);

void DoSomething(Base* item)
{
   Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(item);

}
```

Or a straight-forward approach (if you don't have the right macros):

```
for (std::vector<Base*>::iterator item = myList.begin(); item  != myList.end(); ++item ) { //Iterate through 'myList'
   Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*>(*item );
}
```

Comment: Sorry typo with std::list. (I have that in my real code. My apologies that I cannot put my real code up.. confidentiality/intellectual property reasons) I would still like to use std::list.. can I not iterate through the list somehow? 'Cause I kinda feel that would defeat the purpose of a list if you can't!

Comment: Can you provide an example of how it works? Not sure how to access the specific item in the list through each pass of a for loop.

Comment: You could use an Iterator. or use FOREACH macro or std::foreach ... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator

Comment: So ` list<int>::iterator it; for(it=myList.begin() ; it != myList.end(); it++) { d = (Derived*)it;}` ?? (I would like to select your answer as correct but I'm still left unsure how to iterate through each item of the list and cast it appropriately.. maybe an example how to solve my problem in your answer?)

Comment: There are also other tricks with macros to get C#-like foreach loops (like boost::FOR_EACH)